# Determining order of powers of number whose order is already known in the same ring

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I've made the following observation: the order of $2 \pmod  {201}$ is $66$, and the order of any power of $2$ which divides $66$ is that quotient. For example, the order of $8=2^3 \pmod {201}$ is $22$, which is $\frac{66}{3}$. Similarly, $2^6$ yields $\frac{66}{6}=11$ and so on. However I'm not sure why this is, or if this is already encapsulated in some standard theorem or something of the sort (maybe some consequence of Fermat's Little/Euler's theorem?). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer comes from the theory of cyclic groups.  If $g$ has order $n$, then $g^k$ has order $\dfrac n{\rm{gcd}(n,k)}$.

This works because you are essentially looking at the cyclic group generated by, in your case $2$, within the  group of units of the ring.

Comment: That seems to be above my level at the moment. Is there a way to describe it with some of the more fundamental theorems and results (like those mentioned in my question)?

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to grapple with some of these concepts, to make your understanding complete.

Comment: I see, thanks for the reference!